# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/post-template.php on line 298

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting this error

> Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/post-template.php

Others have suggested using `wp_reset_postdata()` to fix the issue however, it doesnt seem to work.

I have the code from the `post-template.php` below:

```
// If post password required and it doesn't match the cookie.
    if ( post_password_required( $post ) )
    return get_the_password_form( $post );

if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) // if the requested page doesn't exist
    $page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist

$content = $pages[$page - 1];
if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches ) ) {
    $content = explode( $matches[0], $content, 2 );
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $more_link_text ) )
        $more_link_text = strip_tags( wp_kses_no_null( trim( $matches[1] ) ) );

    $has_teaser = true;
} else {
    $content = array( $content );
}

if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--noteaser-->' ) && ( ! $multipage || $page == 1 ) )
    $strip_teaser = true;

$teaser = $content[0];

if ( $more && $strip_teaser && $has_teaser )
    $teaser = '';

$output .= $teaser;
```

Here are my post functions/queries

```
function my_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {

ob_start();
$count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
?><a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url();   ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php
if ( $count > 0 ) {
    ?>
    <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo esc_html( $count ); ?></span>
    <?php
}
    ?></a><?php

  $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

  return $fragments;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments',    'my_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );

function global_menu($location,$class){
     wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location'  => $location,//primary
      'depth'             => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
      'container'       => null,
      'menu_class'      => $class,//navbar-nav mr-auto
      'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
      'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
      ) );
    }
    add_filter( 'menu-init', 'global_menu' );

function portal_cart_link($url) {
    ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', permaslug() ); ?>">
            <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();?></span>
        </a>
    <?php
}
add_filter( 'woo-init', 'portal_cart_link' );
function product_query() {

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            if($loop->have_posts()):while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                global $product;
                echo '<div class="col-md-3 product"><a  href="'.get_permalink().'"><img class="img-responsive" src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID) .'"  /><br /><h3 class="text-center">'    . get_the_title() . '</h3></a></div>';
            endwhile;endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_filter( 'woo-init', 'product_query' );
```

Comment: which line is `298`?

Comment: @Samuel it is the line with 

`if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--noteaser-->' ) && ( ! $multipage || $page == 1 ) )
    $strip_teaser = true;`

Comment: Your error is then coming from `$post`. If it's not an `obj` then what is it? Can you use `var_dump` to see what the output is?